# empty (nil) uiimage picked from photo library

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

I have am picking an image from the photo library like this

```
 UIImagePickerController *pickerLibrary = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
pickerLibrary.delegate = self;
pickerLibrary.allowsEditing = YES;
pickerLibrary.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
[self presentViewController:pickerLibrary animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

and to load the image I do this

```
- (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)pickerLibrary didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo
{
    NSLog(@"picked image: %@", image);
    self.img = image;
}
```

it causes the following error

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'CALayerInvalidGeometry', reason: 'CALayer position contains NaN: [160 nan]'
```

I've been looking on SO but couldn't find anything that solves my problem. ideas? probably sth rather simple?

Answer (score 0):

ok, the problem seemed to be that I had forgotten to delete an old

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
```

from an earlier version of my taking a photo code. Now it looks like it's working correctly

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
    UIImage *image=[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
    self.img = image;
}];
}
```